# Internal server error after installing PHP7, how to fix?

Tags: php, magento, internal-server-error, php-7

We were running PHP 5.4 on our server. The OS of the server is CentOS. Unfortunately, for the CMS we want to install (Magento 2), we need a later version.

So I installed PHP 7 according to the steps at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#php-centos-7. (At some of the command I placed `sudo` in front of it, and at step 3 I added `--skip-broken` because it did not work without it.)

The end of the installing went like this:

```
    Installing : php70u-common-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                    1/15
    Installing : php70u-cli-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                       2/15
    Installing : php70u-pdo-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                       3/15
    Installing : libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64                                  4/15
    Installing : libicu-4.2.1-14.el6.x86_64                                  5/15
    Installing : php70u-intl-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                      6/15
    Installing : php70u-gd-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                        7/15
    Installing : php70u-mysqlnd-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                   8/15
    Installing : php70u-devel-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                     9/15
    Installing : php70u-xml-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                      10/15
    Installing : php70u-opcache-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                  11/15
    Installing : php70u-bcmath-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                   12/15
    Installing : php70u-json-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                     13/15
    Installing : php70u-mbstring-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                 14/15
    Installing : php70u-mcrypt-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                   15/15
    Verifying  : php70u-xml-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                       1/15
    Verifying  : php70u-cli-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                       2/15
    Verifying  : php70u-opcache-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                   3/15
    Verifying  : libicu-4.2.1-14.el6.x86_64                                  4/15
    Verifying  : libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64                                  5/15
    Verifying  : php70u-bcmath-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                    6/15
    Verifying  : php70u-json-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                      7/15
    Verifying  : php70u-devel-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                     8/15
    Verifying  : php70u-gd-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                        9/15
    Verifying  : php70u-common-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                   10/15
    Verifying  : php70u-mbstring-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                 11/15
    Verifying  : php70u-mysqlnd-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                  12/15
    Verifying  : php70u-mcrypt-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                   13/15
    Verifying  : php70u-pdo-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                      14/15
    Verifying  : php70u-intl-7.0.8-1.ius.centos6.x86_64                  15/15

    Installed:
    php70u-bcmath.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-common.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-devel.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-gd.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-intl.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-json.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-mcrypt.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-opcache.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-pdo.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6
    php70u-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6

    Dependency Installed:
    libicu.x86_64 0:4.2.1-14.el6                 libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6
    php70u-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6

    Skipped (dependency problems):
    mod_php70u.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.ius.centos6

    Complete!
```

But when I visit the website again, the only thing I get is:

[image]

In the error logs it shows:

```
[Tue Jul 05 15:09:46 2016] [error] [client 145.132.179.108] File does not exist: /home/trade4deals/public_html/500.shtml
```

When I enter the command `php -v` it still says it is using PHP 5.4.42:

```
PHP 5.4.42 (cli) (built: Jun 29 2015 18:08:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

What can I do? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like an Apache error log entry and I would imagine that there are plenty just like it even before your upgrade.

Comment: Assuming that your PHP install went well then you just need to update Apache's configuration file, point it to the new PHP install, and restart Apache.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus How do I do that?

Comment: This is a server management question, best asked over in one of the sections that deals with webserver/php setups as opposed to being asked in a application programming section.

Comment: @FiascoLabs How can I go to that section?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kevin How did you end up fixing this? I'm having a same issue.

Comment: @user1448031 Sorry, I don't know anymore. I propably restored the server to a backup.